# How to read wiring diagram of old zoning board

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I'm trying to make a smart thermostat to work with my old zoning panel (20-ish years old?) in my house. The model is called MASTERTROL MINI-ZONE-3. It's mostly standard but with one quirk:

> The Zone 1 Thermostat requires a manual changeover subbase with “O” and “B” terminals. **The “O” terminal must make with R when the subbase is switched to the COOL Mode. The “B” terminal must make with R when the subbase is switched to the HEAT Mode.** When the Zone 1 Subbase in either the Heat or Cool Mode, any one of the 3 zone thermo- stats can call for the respective mode.

(See wiring diagram below)

I think what this says is that in addition to regular wiring (Y-R for cooling, W-R for heating, etc), it requires a connection between O (or B) and R to set the mode (which seems redundant to me).

If that's true, then I should be able to just connect O and R using a connector (in the winter; and manually changeover in the summer), and wire Y,W,G,R,C to the thermostat.

Can someone help me understand the internal wiring diagram (the second figure) to verify if the plan looks reasonable?

The complete manual can be found at https://www.manualsdir.com/manuals/98411/honeywell-mm3-mastertrol-mm-3.html.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What make and model is your smart thermostat, and what are you using for thermostats on the other zones?

Comment: Currently, my zone 1 is https://www.honeywellhome.com/us/en/products/air/thermostats/non-programmable-thermostats/digital-non-programmable-thermostat-low-volt-rth111b1024-e1/, and other zones are using something dumber. My smart thermostat is a Nest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Getting everything to play nice isn't going to be easy

Your old zoning board was designed to use a mechanical heat pump thermostat for Zone 1, where both O and B come directly off contacts on the mode select switch and thus are both available at all times.  Modern thermostats like the Nest, though, only provide a single, configurable reversing valve output though as heat pumps only need one or the other, never both at once.

Furthermore, most modern thermostats only drive O/B when configured to run a heat pump.  However, when configured in that fashion, they run their Y output for both heating *and* cooling, which'll confuse your zone board if you try to hook it up directly.

As a result, you'll need to add a *relay* to adapt your thermostat to your zone board.  The good news is that finding a suitable one isn't hard: a White-Rodgers 90-340 or other equivalent 24VAC-coiled DPDT fan relay will do the trick, or you can use a RIBMN2401D and a short length of 2.75" mounting track instead if HVAC-style fan relays are unacceptable for some reason.

Wiring is where things get challenging though.  The coil terminals of whatever relay you pick are easy: one goes to the C (1) terminal on the zone board, while the other connects to the O/B wire coming from the Nest.  The contacts are where things get challenging though:

- One COM terminal on the relay goes to the R (2) terminal on the zone board
- The other COM terminal on the relay goes to the Y wire coming from the Nest
- The NO terminal corresponding with the first COM terminal connects to the O1 terminal on the zone board
- The NC terminal corresponding with the first COM terminal connects to the B1 terminal on the zone board
- The NO terminal corresponding with the second COM terminal connects to the Zone 1 Y/T6 terminal on the zone board
- and the NC terminal corresponding with the second COM terminal connects to the Zone 1 W/T4 terminal on the zone board

From there, the thermostat simply has R/Rc and C brought over from terminals 2 and 1 on the zone board, with W left unconnected.  The G terminal, though, is a special beast that we will address next.

### New wine, old skins

The primary problem with old zoning boards like yours, once you get past the fundamental issues with the Variable Air Volume zoning system they are trying to implement (and oh, there are many issues with VAV, but they are out of scope for this answer), is that they were designed to work in an electromechanical-thermostat era, where things like having both and O and a B signal at once without having the Y output energized in both modes were possible.  More annoyingly though, you'll note that the R terminals on zones 2 and 3 don't connect to the transformer 24V supply, but to a relay coil instead!  As a result, you'll be stuck with mechanical thermostats on the remaining zones until you upgrade the zoning board itself or apply further hackery, and furthermore, zone 1 is the only zone that can call for fan as a result.

So, we have to punt here and wire G from the Nest to the G1 terminal on the zoning board.  (It'd be possible to use more relays to interface smarter thermostats to the remaining zones, but it'd require two relays for each zone, so you might as well replace the whole board at that point.)

Comment: I’ve not thought of adding a relay but that’s an interesting idea. I have two questions. First, I was thinking of a less elegant solution where I install a manual SPDT switch near furnace to connect R to O or B, then simply run C, Y, W, G, R to Nest. Is there any problem with that (other than needing manual changeover, which I’m fine with). Second, how big of a job it is to change the board? Is it likely to involve changing the damper motors too?

Comment: You should be able to use the existing damper motors with a new board provided it's configured correctly.  As to the idea of a manual changeover switch, the main issue with that is that it won't be synchronized with the Nest's auto-changeover functionality, so you could have the Nest calling for cooling while your switch is set for heating, or vice versa, which'd confuse the poor Nest to no end

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite common for heat pumps. They run pretty much the same way whether heating or cooling, with one change to switch modes. With only one zone this would not make a lot of sense, because you would have two switches:

- Heat on/off
- Cool on/off

or

- Heat/Cool on/off
- O/B on/off (or "O vs. B")

However, with 3 zones this actually makes a lot of sense. First of all, you cut down on the number of switches. Instead of:

- Heat 1 on/off
- Heat 2 on/off
- Heat 3 on/off
- Cool 1 on/off
- Cool 2 on/off
- Cool 3 on/off

you have:

- Heat/Cool 1 on/off
- Heat/Cool 2 on/off
- Heat/Cool 3 on/off
- O/B

Plus this makes it impossible to call for heat in one part of the house and cool in another. Depending on system design, doing that could break something or cause the system to heat and cool at the same time (a big waste of energy) or just pick one mode (and the people who want the other think it is broken blowing cool air when they asked for heat or vice versa).

This is actually quite common now. So all you need is a thermostat that supports multiple zones *and* supports O/B. Or it may be advertised as supporting heat pumps - but when you get to the installation instructions, it should mention O/B. The major brands of thermostats all support O/B, though not necessarily on every model. Multiple zones is a little more unusual, but it is available.

One catch (thank you ThreePhaseEel): The more common method is a single O/B wire - i.e., power on the wire is for heat and no power is for cool (or maybe vice versa). However, you have the somewhat less common *separate* O and B connections. In a quick search, it does look like at least *some* major brand thermostats should be compatible, but you will likely be more limited than an "O/B" system.

Comment: Note that the OP's zoning board requires *both* O *and* B to be provided from the changeover subbase, not a single O/B signal as you find on most modern heat pump thermostats

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You're right. I didn't catch that. But in a quick search, it looks like there should be some compatible stuff out there.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. It's very hard to find a smart thermostat with separate O and B. (My current one, which is not smart, is from [Honeywell](https://www.honeywellhome.com/us/en/products/air/thermostats/non-programmable-thermostats/digital-non-programmable-thermostat-low-volt-rth111b1024-e1/).) That's why I'm thinking of adding a manual switch between O, B, and R.