# Do I have a C wire (or something I can repurpose)?

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire

Pretty old looking thermostat, but the house itself isn't that old (I think 1997).

There's no terminal with a "C" at all here, but there's 6 wires including a "blue one" which this rookie has heard often denotes C.

I want to install a smart thermostat here that will require a C... can I?

Thank you!

Edit: Added pic from the air-handler side per comments

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of AC is that  ? with what type of heating ? is it heat pump system

Comment: It will be helpful to also see the connections at the furnace/air handler end.

Comment: Is it that B is reserved for Black now and C is for Cyan?

Comment: What kind of thermostat is it?  As in, does it contain any electronics or is it purely mechanical?  I've yet to see a mechanical thermostat that needs a C wire so if this is mechanical then there's likely no C wire.  If the thermostat needs batteries to run then there's a good chance there's no C wire.  If the thermostat is electronic and has to batteries then there's likely a C wire.  I use "likely" and "chance" because there are exceptions but we can start with finding some odds.

Comment: "Is it that B is reserved for Black now and C is for Cyan?"  Looking at some thermostat install instructions it appears that at some point common was indicated with a black (or "B") wire.  Apparently this standard changed to a blue wire, but the letter code chosen for it was "C" for "common".  Using "B" as a label could confuse people as that could mean brown or blue.  Older systems apparently used brown for heat pumps but I guess orange is the new brown.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at your air-handler furnace please?

Comment: The C is always present at the furnace since it is the 0v end of the transformer that supplies 24v. The question becomes "how easy/hard is it to tap this connection". The complication is 5 wire cable typically doesn't leave a wire for this so you need to steal the G wire, which is really no problem since rarely does anyone need to run the fan in "fan only" mode. **A picture of the furnace wiring diagram is the only way to determine the difficulty of your installation.**

Comment: @NoSparksPlease  The fan control wire is not only for that fan control switch from auto to on, it is quite typically required for proper operation of an air conditioner or electric heat.  I recall in doing a thermostat replacement that the fan wasn't running with the heat.  I discovered that there was a setting in the thermostat for "electric" (meaning the thermostat turns on the fan during heating) or "fossil fuel" (meaning the furnace will turn on the fan when heating).  The label of "electric" vs. "fossil fuel" means nothing but how things are typically done, there will be exceptions.

Comment: OK- I added a pic from the air-handler side

Comment: Thanks for the photo, that should help plenty.  Any idea which cable goes to thermostat?  I assume it is the one on the far left, if so then the blue and brown wires appear unused so either (though preferably blue to keep with the standard) can be used for the C-wire.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have slightly complicated system that as currently configured will not work well with a smart thermostat.

That Mastertrol Minizone system is a zone controller that takes advantage of how old mechanical thermostats work.

The second thermostat (the one connected with 3 instead of 6 wires) actually has the electricity flow backwards from how it normally does for a thermostat.

For the main thermostat it is making "clever" use of how the heatpump reverse valve terminals are wired to the heat/cool manual switch.

You would really want to switch that system out for a more modern zone controller like the Honeywell HZ311. This costs about $132 on amazon and could likely be fairly easilly self installed in this scenario, since they both use the same transformer specifications, allowing you to reuse the existing one.

If you really want to keep your existing system then you can [see ThreePhaseEel's post about how this might be accomplished, and the caveats](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/264090/5816).

To switch to the newer controller, you would want to initially hook it up to your existing thermostats to make sure everything works, and then you could install new thermostats that need a C wire.

To start, you would disconnect the O and B wires from the existing thermostat, as the new zone control board would not be creatively reusing those like the old one did, but merely needs the normal 4 (R Y W and G)

You would then move the wires from the left most terminal block to the matching letters in the HZ311's "equipment" section. Just like currently there should be a little jumper wire between Rh and Rc, which is likely pre-installed for you in HZ311.

The little red and white wire at the bottom of second terminal block from the left to the power terminal of the HZ311 (order does not matter).

For the zone 1 thermostat (the one connected to the middle two terminal blocks), you would connect it to the zone one thermostat. You would only initially connect the R W Y and G to the existing thermostat. You would move the zone 1 damper wires (M1 M4 M6) from that third from the left terminal block to the corresponding zone 1 damper terminals on the new controller.

The right most terminal block has your zone 2 thermostat and damper, and would just match them to same named terminals in the zone 2 section of the HZ311. That thermostat is only 3 wire.

Then using both your existing thermostats, test both heat and cooling. If everything checks out then installing a smart thermostat should be easy. The one that used to have 6 wires connected would only have 4 connected, so one of the others can become C, and get connected to C on your zone controller, and the C spot on your smart thermostat. As for your other thermostat, well it is only using 3 of the 6 wires in its cable, so plenty of room for connecting C there too if desired.